# How to pass two parameters in a template function in series.Line in kendo line chart

Tags: kendo-ui

I have implemented a Kendo line chart using ASP.NET. As in the kendo examples shown i have used series{} to display lines. I have written my own custom template in series.Line to display the labels for markers when mouse hovered.But i need to pass two parameters to that function.

```
 series.Line(m => m.Values[0].value).Labels(lbl => lbl.Position(ChartPointLabelsPosition.Above).Visible(true).Template("#= formatLabelForEffort(category#"))
```

In the above code formatLabelForEffort() is the function call written in the template which has only one arguement called category. I want to send another arguement in the same function. The second arguiement would be an array. How would i achieve this. Please help me out to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared a demo of this for you: 
[custom template passing in options.](http://dojo.telerik.com/IzAMu/2)

All you need to do is change your existing function from:

```
.Template("#= formatLabelForEffort(category)#")
```

to

```
 .Template("#= formatLabelForEffort(category, dataItem)#")
```

as long as the array is part of the original data model that is being bound within the series you should be able to alter your function to handle the code.

then using my version of your function:

```
function formatLabelForEffort(category,dataItem){
      var retString = '';
      console.log(dataItem);
      if (dataItem.myArray !== undefined && 
          dataItem.myArray !== null &&  
          dataItem.myArray !== null &&
          dataItem.myArray.length > 0)
      {
        retString = 'Category is:: ' + category + '\r\n' ;
        retString += kendo.stringify(dataItem.myArray) ;
      }
      else 
      {
        retString = 'Category is:: ' + category;
      }

      console.log(retString);

      return kendo.htmlEncode(retString);
    }
```

we simply check to ensure the array is present and then return a string accordingly.

for more info on what you can pass to the series labels check this link:

[series label template configuration](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.labels.template)

any further issues give me a shout and I will expand where I can.